# iOS app with hardware integration

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I want to develop an iOS app that uses an external hardware plug-in, kind of like Square https://squareup.com. However I was unable to find any references in Apple's documentation. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: You should look at External Accessory framework in iOS documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use the iPod connector to connect to your hardware, the only option is the [External Accessory](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009502) framework. Be advised that you must be a registered accessory developer (more expensive than the standard developer license).

I believe Square uses the audio input (others may correct me), an ingenious hack that doesn't require use of the iPod connector. If your hardware can operate over (analog) audio in/out, that might be an option to consider.

Answer (score 1):

This book might help you: [Building iPhone OS Accessories: Use the iPhone Accessories API to Control and Monitor Devices](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430229315)

Answer (score 1):

In order to develop hardware accessories, you must be a member of Apple's MFi program. Despite what the user above stated, it doesn't cost anything. But it does require a lot more work than becoming an app developer.

Accessories don't necessarily need to go through the MFi process if they are NOT over 30pin connector OR bluetooth (ie, the Square connecter goes through the headphone port, or any WiFi accessories).