# MFI Apple Program/Certification

Tags: ios, external-accessory, mfi

For a startup, what are the parameters that can make the certification request approved by Apple?

I know there are 2 types of certification described in FAQs [here](http://mfi.apple.com/faqs.html)

they say:

> high-volume manufacturing facility are eligible for the MFi Manufacturing License.

high-volume = ????

I'm interested in building MFI accessories and apps needed to control them.

Of course, my interest in do this is to make some profits, but I don't know what are the parameters that make the MFI Program valid as manufactorer (I sent the Apple MFI request to enter in the program)

I prefer not to use [this](http://www.redpark.com/) kind of solution, just want to sell my own accessories.

I am waiting for Apple review to my MFI Program request and I explained them my type of accessories is on music area.

If is too complicated, I would like to know if it's possible to communicate with external devices via USB cable (Arduino or MSP430) having only the iOS Developer Program (maybe using [EAAccessory library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/EAAccessory_class/Reference/Reference.html)) and build products to sell.

Comment: a possible fix to my problem is described in another answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317740/ios-app-with-hardware-integration

but my question persist: "can I put my product in the market without any problems?"

Comment: anyone can help me? tell me if my question it's not clear

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dario;

If you want to have your accessory connect through a 30-pin connector, or the new Lightning connector, or if you want any user-developed apps to communicate with the accessory through the iOS "External Accessory Framework", the accessory must be developed under a MFi license.

Any USB communications with the iOS devices would require use of the the 30-pin connector or the Lightning connector.

You should note that Apple will only grant MFi licenses to corporate entities that meet their criteria, and are willing to undergo a credit check. Additionally, after a recent restructuring of the MFi program, MFi accessories can now only be manufactured by companies that have been granted a "MFi Manufacturing License". As stated on the FAQ, Apple will only grant the Manufacturing License to companies that own a high-volume manufacturing facility. Only companies that have been granted a MFi Manufacturing License can buy the proprietary components that make it possible for accessories to connect to iOS devices, or communicate with user-developed apps through the iOS External Accessory Framework.

So, the realistic answer to your question, "can I put my product in the market without any problems?" is pretty simply, no.

Some other options would be to implement an accessory that communicates with the iPhone through wi-fi, or implement a  "Bluetooth-LE" accessory that can communicate with user-developed apps through the CoreBluetooth Framework.

If you choose the Bluetooth-LE option, though, keep in mind that iOS devices before the iPhone 4S or iPad 3rd gen don't have the hardware to support Bluetooth-LE.

In any case, you'll have to get your app approved by Apple before it can be made available through the app store.

Comment: thanks a lot. I was thinking about communicating with the ear mic/earphones and send/receive impulse that the app would recognize, but as you stated, Apple probably woun't let me publish this kind of app in the store... any suggestion? work around? thanks again

Comment: @DarioRusignuolo Apple has allowed that type of app into the App Store. Look into the [Hijack](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~prabal/projects/hijack/) project.

Answer (score 5):

Dario;

The latest changes to Apple's MFi Licensing structure have closed off any opportunities for small companies and "start ups" to market "wired" iOS accessories. The entry requirements for a MFi Developer License aren't too difficult to meet, so it is still possible for small companies to develop MFi accessories. However, finding a "MFi Manufacturing Licensee" company that will be willing to take your design through the Apple certification process, and then manufacture the accessory for you, is likely to be an insurmountable obstacle for most small companies or "start-ups".

That leaves three "wireless" options... Bluetooth MFi, Bluetooth-LE and wi-fi. Unfortunately, the new MFi requirements appear to also apply to Bluetooth MFi accessories, leaving Bluetooth-LE and wif-fi as the only realistic options.

If your accessory has modest requirements for data throughput, Bluetooth-LE is probably your best bet. Assuming you meet all other regulatory requirements, for emissions, safety, etc., you'll be able to market your product without any constraints posed by Apple. The other side of this coin is that you can't use any of the Apple "trade dress" on your product or packaging. It's pretty  clear that Apple is willing to approve properly designed apps that interface with Bluetooth-LE accessories.

As I indicated before, though, only the latest iOS devices (iPhone 4S, iPad 3rd gen, etc.) have the RF hardware neccessary to support Bluetooth-LE.

You can find a wealth of information regarding Bluetooth-LE accessories in archives of the "Bluetooth-dev" area of lists.apple.com. The corresponding CoreBluetooth framework is open to all Apple iOS developers.

If a Bluetooth-LE solution won't work for you, wi-fi is the only other viable choice. As with Bluetooth-LE accessories, there are many examples of Apple-approved apps that work with unique wi-fi accessories.

Regards,

Mark Davis

Comment: Mark, you explained well what I am looking for. I didn't know about Bluetooth LE. I knew that Blootooth MFi is locked as the accessory usb interface to that companies having the Apple approvement. For what concern my project, building a small wifi accessory capable lead an high cost external device, I would stay with Bluetooth (I just need to send few simple commands). will read the CoreBluetooth framework doc... thanks man!

Comment: Dario... Texas Instruments has some ready-to-run iOS compatible Bluetooth-LE examples on their web-site. And be sure to look through the archives in the Bluetooth-dev section of the Apple-sponsered lists.apple.com forum!